# Generating a product count per category in magento (inc sub cats)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, magento

I need to build a mysql table with product counts for every product in the db against every category and its sub categories.

IE a single product might have several applications (Ford, Vauxhal, Jaguar) and several models (Mondeo, Astra, XJ8) for example.

I've build a module that allows the user to search for products that fit specific manufacturers/models and filter by category. Because of the huge number of possible matches it needs this summary table to keep track of the counts.

So I need to be able to quickly query the table to fetch counts for every category for a specific make and/or model.

I did have an sql script that generated these counts quite quickly however it doesn't work on the live system because it can't take into account the fact a category might have no products assigned to it directly but its sub cats might do (and the sub cats of the sub cats et al).

Can anybody suggest an SQL query for magento that might provide these details for me? I have one table that has a list of makes/models and the product ID's applicable to them...

Comment: why you are not using mangento's attributes for the models/manufactures and use the mangento's builtin orm to query with filter attribute

Comment: That is a jolly good question! I didn't build the site and it has lots of other custom modules that rely on this bizarre setup...